# SQL Server PIVOT Function To Switch Rows, Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to switch rows and columns with PIVOT (or another method). The documentation is pretty confusing to me. Thanks

```
DECLARE @CallCenterID Int;
DECLARE @BeginDateofReview SmallDateTime;
DECLARE @EndDateofReview SmallDateTime;

SELECT 
    COUNT(case when Score_Greeting = 'Yes' then Score_Greeting END) AS Score_Greeting_Passed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score_Greeting IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Score_Greeting_Reviewed,     
    ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(4,1), (COUNT(CASE WHEN Score_Greeting = 'Yes' THEN Score_Greeting END) * 100.0) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN Score_Greeting IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0),0),0) AS Score_Greeting_PctngPassed,  
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Score_Authentication = 'Yes' THEN Score_Authentication END) AS Score_Authentication_Passed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score_Authentication IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Score_Authentication_Reviewed,     
    ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(4,1), (COUNT(CASE WHEN Score_Authentication = 'Yes' THEN Score_Authentication END) * 100.0) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN Score_Authentication IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0), 0), 0) AS Score_Authentication_PctngPassed,   
FROM 
    Calls
WHERE 
    CallCenterID = @CallCenterID AND
    (DateofReview >= @BeginDateofReview AND DateofReview <= @EndDateofReview)
```

Desired results:

```
Score_Greeting_Passed   5
Score_Greeting_Reviewed 9
Score_Greeting_PctngPassed  56
Score_Authentication_Passed 6
Score_Authentication_Reviewed   9
Score_Authentication_PctngPassed    67
```

Comment: You realise that we can't run your SQL, as we don't have access to your SQL Server (or data) right? Also, you haven't declared your variables; so we don't know what they contain. Have a look at the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page on how to post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **UNPIVOT** operator to transpose the rows and columns. If we assume your query above is stored in @YourData, it's going to be something like:

```
SELECT
    UnpivotedData.ScoreType
,   UnpivotedData.ScoreValue
FROM
    @YourData
UNPIVOT (ScoreValue FOR ScoreType IN ( [Score_Greeting_Passed], [Score_Greeting_Reviewed], [Score_Greeting_PctngPassed], 
        [Score_Authentication_Passed], [Score_Authentication_Reviewed], [Score_Authentication_PctngPassed] )) AS UnpivotedData
```